# spring security intercept wrong password

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring security. I am using aspectj to log wrong username or password. I was able to intercept wrong username by checking loadUserByUsername for an exception. How do i intercept wrong password.

Looks like Spring gets the user object and check for the entered password against user password. How can i intercept this for any exception

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have much idea about aspects so this *may* not help.

Firstly, you need to ask yourself, do you really need to distinguish between a wrong username and a wrong password - especially if this information is returned to the user.

By default spring-security does not encourage this, which is why by default it returns a `BadCredentialsException` in either case.

Spring security `3.0.x` provides a `public` `authenticate()` method (in `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` class) which first retrieves the user in the `protected` `retrieveUser`() method and then does password validation in the `protected` `additionalAuthenticationChecks()` method.

By setting the property `hideUserNotFoundExceptions` to `false` (it is `true` by default), `authenticate()` method can be checked for `UserNotFoundException` (in case of wrong user) and `BadCredentialsException` in case of wrong password.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use *ExceptionTranslationFilter* and *FilterSecurityInterceptor* to handle all authentication failures. You may want to review [The Security Filter Chain](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html) page and add some clarification to you question if this doesn't give you what you need.

Comment: can you help me with some code sample. To weave an aspect, I need to provide some method that needs to be checked. Being new to spring security, not sure, which class to extend and which method to check if the password is incorrect.